# Failed to create component "MetroTextBox" in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, nuget-package

I am trying to create a POS System using C# in Visual Studio. Then, I decided to apply the Metro UI Framework to my project. But whenever I use it, this same error appears:

[image]

I tried everything like adding this in my code:

```
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
```

But I still got an error. Please help me solve this, I am new to C# in Visual Studio.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538550/how-do-i-add-the-metro-ui-controls-to-the-toolbox-in-visual-studio

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions. It fixed some of the MetroUI features. But the MetroTextBox still doesn't work. Does it mean I can't use it?

Comment: You are getting an error indicating the control doesn't contain data.  Net has Window Controls (WCF) and WindowForm controls which are not compatible.  Not sure if you can use it or not.  Looks like from link I provided that is can be done.  The error indicates a issue when a connection is being made from client to server.  The client and server are two different applications.  A control in client cannot be used in the server.  The data inside the control in client has to be transmitter to server and then put back into a new control.  The control cannot be transmitter from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case, changing the dotnet version from 6.0 to 4.8.1, it was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).